# Excel Automation Error

Tags: excel, vba, ado

I am getting an "Automation Error" on the line `rstLgn_details.Open SqlCmd`

This is the Code.

```
Call ConnectSS_Param(ThisWorkbook.FullName)    

Set rstLgn_details = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set SqlCmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set SqlparamUserID = SqlCmd.CreateParameter("@UserID", 129, 1, 52, txtUsername.Value)

StrSql = "SELECT Capabilityname,SLAA_EID FORM $Login_Details WHERE SLAA_EID=@UserID"

SqlCmd.ActiveConnection = conndb
SqlCmd.CommandText = StrSql
SqlCmd.Parameters.Append SqlparamUserID            

rstLgn_details.Open SqlCmd

If rstLgn_details.RecordCount > 0 Then         
   UserName = rstLgn_details(1)
   CapHlded = rstLgn_details(0)
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Serach").Select
Else  
   MsgBox "Sorry You are Not Authorized for this..... ", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Invaild User"
End If
```

Comment: Well for one thing you have FORM instead of `FROM`.

Comment: Thanks.... Jim for taking time and answering this..

Answer (score 0):

When you reconnect to the Excel Workbook, the original file closes and all the references set to the original file are no longer valid.  You'll get the `Automation Error`  when you try use one of the invalid references.

Here is an exert from [Automation Error Using Excel Object in Visual Basic Procedure](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/134835)

This problem occurs when you access a Microsoft Excel OLE Automation object in a Visual Basic procedure while Microsoft Excel is closed. If, for example, you create a reference for a worksheet object using the CreateObject function, and you create a reference for another Microsoft Excel object using the GetObject function in your procedure, if you then set the Microsoft Excel worksheet object (Excel.Sheet) equal to nothing, you receive the OLE Automation error message if you then try to access the other object.